# issues with DEFAULT values

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create Table payment_record(
payment_record_id int NOT NULL,
payment_number Varchar(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
recieved_from_client Number (8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
Paid_to_client Number (8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
payment_date Date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(payment_record_id));
```

outcome

```
SQL> create Table payment_record(
 2  payment_record_id int NOT NULL,
 3  payment_number Varchar(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 4  recieved_from_client Number (8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
 5  Paid_to_client Number (8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
 6  payment_date Date NOT NULL,
 7  PRIMARY KEY(payment_record_id));
 recieved_from_client Number (8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
                                       *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Please what am I getting wrong? Am trying to create a table where defaultly the

```
Paid_to_client 
recieved_from_client
```

can produce 0.00 if values as not assign to it

Answer (score 3):

The `default` clause should come before the `NOT NULL` specification:

```
SQL> create Table payment_record(
 2  payment_record_id int NOT NULL,
 3  payment_number Varchar(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 4  recieved_from_client Number (8,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL,
 5  Paid_to_client Number (8,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL,
 6  payment_date Date NOT NULL,
 7  PRIMARY KEY(payment_record_id));
```

Answer (score 3):

DEFAULT goes before NOT NULL:

```
create Table payment_record(
payment_record_id int NOT NULL,
payment_number Varchar(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
recieved_from_client Number (8,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL,
Paid_to_client Number (8,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL ,
payment_date Date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(payment_record_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use default before column constraint for example not null. For [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtable.html)